# EJS - Scripts in wrong location

Tags: ejs, express-4

*In the interest of DRY, I have 3 page types in my SPA: **(1)Layout**, **(2)Index**, and **(3)XXXX (view)**.
Layout has the body related tags, Index the nav system, and XXXX the relative content. Here is the code:*

**Layout.ejs:**

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE> 
> <html> 
> <head>
> <title>Index Page</title>
> <% include ../includes/styles%>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
> </head>
>  <body>
> </body>
> <% include ../includes/scripts%> 
> </html>
> ```

**Index.ejs:**

> ```
> <% include ../includes/layout %>
> <h1>This is where the nav bar goes</h1>
> <div data-ng-view></div>
> ```

*View pages not important for this problem.
What I noticed is that my sccript tags from layout are above the body's children DOMs, not at all what I wanted.
What I wanted is:*

> ----- body
>
> ```
>    --- content
> ```
>
> ----- scripts

*What must I do in layout.ejs to keep the script tags at the bottom of the final html page?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejs-locals does not support Express 4.x.

I opted for creating a custom engine.